# How to write a directive to change isolate scope value of another directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

I want to extend a directive's functionality. Here is my template:

```
  <input type="text" color="ctrl.color" color-changer="" />
```

and the color directive is:

```
app.directive("color", [function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      color: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      scope.$watch("color", function(){
        iElement.css("background-color", scope.color);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

I want to write a directive (named `color-changer`) to change the color value of the other directive when I focus on `input`. How can I write this directive.

**PS:** I don't want to recompile all of the element. It works but is very slow.

**PS:** Actually I want to change the value bound to `color` attribute to trigger `$watch`

Comment: You can take the same code that you wrap under a iElement[0].on('focus')

Comment: i think you need to do it from the parent scope, parent scope can be of a controller or a directive.

Comment: @clement_frndz This is the simplified example I've written here. Actually I can't change the color directive.

Comment: Doesn't a second iElement.css() on focus override the first ?

Comment: @atinder Would you please provide me your suggested solution? I don't know what `color` bound to.

Comment: one way can be `<input type="text" color="ctrl.color" ng-model="ctrl.color" />`. Chaning value in the input will change the color attribute value on the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem:

```
app.directive("colorChanger", ["$parse", function($parse){
  return {
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs){
      iElement.on("focus", function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          $parse(iAttrs.color).assign(scope, "green");
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Soemthing like this should work:

```
myApp.directive("colorChanger", [function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      colorChanger: "="
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="colorChanger">'
  };
}]);
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16774/